# How to stop Intellij from automatically switching console focus on output

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm running multiple processes in Intellij and they are all sending output to their own consoles are varying rates. One console sends new output at intervals of about 4 or 5 seconds while the other consoles receive output less frequently.

While looking at one of the "other"consoles the focus is repeatedly and automatically taken away and redirected to the console with recent output. Is there a way to stop this behavior in Intellij?

I'd like to be able to switch back and forth among the consoles when I want to so that I can remained focused on the log output of a particular process.

Thanks in advance for any ideas and suggestions. Was not able to find any helpful info in the Intellij docs. Maybe the feature I am suggesting does not exit.

Comment: sounds like a bug

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA